# Do I have to worry if somebody tried to reset my Facebook password?

Tags: security, passwords, gmail, facebook

I have got this email earlier which asked me that **I have requested t change the password of my FB account** which I didn't.

[image]

I refused the request for that and haven't changed the password of my Gmail or Facebook account, but I'm little worried about safety of my account.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Could you open it in the 'full' gmail webpage and see the original source? this should tell you the *real* e mail address sent from. Its probably an attempt to phish you and is best ignored, deleted and sent to /dev/null

Comment: I had checked that on webpage and checked original source of that sent from FB and I refused it. The same email address which i get on my email address before.

Comment: Have you clicked the "let us know immedately" link?

Comment: For search, please don't use images while you can simply copy/paste the text. Thanks.

Comment: @gronostaj yep I Did and after that now I've changed password for both accounts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be a phishing scheme. As long as you did not click on any of the links, you should be fine.